# .natvis - how to reference a template template parameter?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, natvis

I'm trying to create a `.natvis` file for visual studio. According to this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx) I can reference a template parameter with `$T1, $T2` and so on. So in the case of `MyClass<A>` `$T1` will reference the type `A`. This works. But in my case `A` is a template itself and I need to reference its parameter, some sort of `$T1<$T1>` - but this obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 11):

With Visual Studio 2015 at least, the template parameter psuedo-variables `$T1`, `$T2`, etc. appear to actually correspond to the wildcards in the type `name' expression, rather than strictly to template parameters.

For example, when

```
<Type Name="outer&lt;*,inner&lt;*&gt;,*&gt">
```

matches against `outer< int, inner< float >, short, long >`, `$T1` expands to `int`, `$T2` expands to `float` and `$T3` expands to `short, long`.